# Writing text on pdf while sliding to new pages

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am using Itext for writing pdf file.

I am reading a file and writing its content to a pdf file.

The problem is that when the file have more then one page the resulting pdf only write one page and a lot of text is not being printed.

I use:

`ColumnText.addElement(Paragraph)`

I guass its happaning beacause the ColumnText is defined in a certain size, but my use of ColumnText is needed for the reason that i am writing the text from right to left and using Hebrew letters, Paragraph dont give support for this (from what i know).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use ColumnText, you need to provide a mechanism that checks when a new page is needed. This is explained in great detail in chapter 3 of "iText in Action". See the examples ColumnMovies and MovieColumns: http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=3

An alternative could be using a PdfPTable. PdfPCell also supports RTL writing. You could create a border-less PdfPTable with one column and one row for each paragraph. When you add this table to the Document, new pages will be added automatically (you may want to change the setSplitLate settings to avoid having too much blank space).